# Graphic tools for development

Tags: linux, python, data-visualization, diagram

I want to develop a python application, with data in mySql. I need a tool package to visualize the data, i.e. make (interactive) reports and diagrams. So something similar to SAS, microstrategy or qlikview. I want to call this framework tool from inside my application so that it generates bar charts, pie diagrams with drill down and text reports with by-groups. Nothing complicated or statistical, a simple pie diagram with 6 segments and the possibility to drill down to the next level.
The tool should also support stored reports and diagrams and allow to user to build new.

Is there any free framework which is (also) usable in linux/python?

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is possibly one of the best tools for data manipulation and visualisation going - especially when used with [iPython](http://ipython.org/) & [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) Notebooks which would let you test your queries & plots outside of your application.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source (BSD Licence)
- Cross Platform
- SQL queries direct from Pandas with `pandas.read_sql, pandas.read_sql_query, pandas.read_sql_table`
- Interfaces easily to [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#mplot3d) which can produce just about any plot or diagram that you can imagine.
- Simple and powerful data manipulation.
- Pandas & matplotlib can be embedded into your application and you can select between various gui frameworks for the application including pygtk, wxpython, tkinter, qt4, or macosx and various graphics file output options including PNG, SVG, PDF & PS.

It is also worth looking at [Plot.ly](http://moderndata.plot.ly/) as in [this](http://moderndata.plot.ly/graph-data-from-mysql-database-in-python/) excellent tutorial, [notebook here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/jackparmer/5485807511a58be48bf2), on generating plot.ly plots from SQL.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your tip with pandas. It looks powerful, but it is not what I look for. For example the user gets a pie chart, wich is showing different percentages in different colors, and he can click on one segment and gets a detailed report about that segment. It's more a GUI thing...

Comment: @jms you can use the above, prototyped in ipython, to produce your charts as files or bitstreams and then display them with your GUI with an action associated with clicking on the chart - the simplest way is to just display it simply and on click get the colour clicked and select the resulting action from a lookup. I've done this sort of thing in wxPython but all should be capable.